# In django choice field key is stored in postgres database instead of value?

Tags: postgresql, django-models, python-3.6, django-2.0, django-2.1

Code:

[image]

django admin
[image]

Error:

[image]

Explain :

see FG,SG - choice field is stored in postgres instead of Federal-gov,State-gov . I dont understand why . Please assist someone.

Comment: [why-not-upload-images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) please replace you image with code it is not hard.

Comment: https://github.com/palani4194/my_modules/blob/cus_mod/adult_dataset/data/models.py 

its my real code please check this  @BearBrown

Comment: Are you available @BearBrown

Comment: do you read my comments? and do you read the text by first comment link?

Comment: i read it . Its hard to copy paste code here. So i added my github code link. Please check second comment. Actually i am new to this stackoverflow. So i dont know how to post questions here. Sorry for disturb you again.

PFA code link:



 https://github.com/palani4194/my_modules/blob/cus_mod/adult_dataset/data/models.py

Comment: sorry but i really think the SO need to make reusable help for all not just for you.

Answer (score 0):

The first element in each tuple is the actual value to be set on the model, and the second element is the human-readable name. You can read more about it in [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-django-field-choices/).
In order to display the human-readable version you can use `fibonacci_inputs_object.get_workclass_display()`. You can check it out in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display).